# Is it possible to take a binary compiled for ARMv7 architecture and convert it to ARMv6?

Tags: tools, compiler, computer-architecture

Is it possible to take a binary compiled for ARMv7 architecture and convert it to ARMv6 ?
Are there any tools that can do this?

Comment: Whether or not this question would be allowed on SO is a question for [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). I'm not entirely sure, so I'm going to leave it for someone else to judge.

Comment: Produced by which compiler? For what platform (OS, etc)? Thumb, not, or both? Using supervisor-only instructions (e.g. messing with the MMU)? Not that I know any, but I suspect partial solutions are a lot easier.   @AnnaLear why wouldn't this question be ok on SO?

Comment: For the Android platform. Not sure about the other questions. :/

Comment: I am just trying to understand why this is not possible, if it is not. Or if it is, then how could it be done?

Comment: There would be two ways you could do this. You can scan the code for any instructions not supported on ARMv6 and replace them with functionally equivalent ARMv6 instructions, relocating as needed. Alternatively, you could trap illegal instruction exceptions, analyze the faulting instruction, create a 'thunk' that does what the instruction should do and replace the faulting instruction with a jump/call to the thunk. That said, I don't know of anyone who has actually done this.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, yes, it is possible. No, there are no tools that can do this, and, in general, it is not recommended. The overhead, performance hit, and human effort required doesn't match the potential reward.